# XDMX cluster setup

Tags: linux, graphics

I am trying to setup a cluster with xdmx to display all of the information from my head node, but I am only getting 16 monitors working with a few problems. I am running CentOS 6.2, but I am wondering if I need to switch distos, or if anyone has a nice guide to setting this up.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. What information are you trying to display from the head node? What happens with the 17th monitor? What are tose monitors, how are they connected to the head?

Comment: I apologize for the vagueness. I have a cluster of 81 computers, 80 of which are all in racks and connected to each other via Ethernet. Then, the 81st computer is the head node which is also connected via Ethernet in the same switch. All of these computers are configured to communicate with each other. What I would like to do is have all 80 of these computers take the desktop from the head node and break it into 80 pieces and display and render it all on their own CPU. Nothing happens with the 17th monitor...I have it configured in a 4 x 4 right now, but can't seem to get past that config.

Comment: So, each node in the cluster has a monitor attached to it, but I have only been able to get a 16 (4x4) portion of the cluster up and running, and it seems to be rendering everything on the head node and then sending it out to the 16 nodes. Does that make sense? I apologize once again if this doesn't make sense, I am new to all of this and am not sure how to explain it. Thanks for the response, I appreciate it!